# Getting an 'invalid File Extension' error on uploading an image file

Tags: php, image, upload

This is my php code to upload a file. The code is showing a Notice for udentified index in the lines where the variables are initiated. Also the output that is displayed is "Invalid File Extension" while I am uploading a jpeg file.

```
<?php


    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        $name     = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $tmpName  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $error    = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        $size     = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $ext      = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        switch ($error) {
            case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
                $valid = true;
                //validate file extensions
                if ( !in_array($ext, array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif')) ) {
                    echo $ext; 
                    $valid = false;
                    $response = 'Invalid file extension.';
                }
                //validate file size
                if ( $size/1024/1024 > 2 ) {
                    $valid = false;
                    $response = 'File size is exceeding maximum allowed size.';
                }
                //upload file
                if ($valid) {
                    $targetPath =  dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $name;
                    move_uploaded_file($tmpName,$targetPath);
                    header( 'Location: index.php' ) ;
                    exit;
                }
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                $response = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                $response = 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                $response = 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                $response = 'No file was uploaded.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                $response = 'Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.3.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                $response = 'Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.';
                break;
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                $response = 'File upload stopped by extension. Introduced in PHP 5.2.0.';
                break;
            default:
                $response = 'Unknown error';
            break;
        }

        echo $response;
    }
    ?>
```

The html file is as follows:

```
<html>
   <body>
     <form method = "post" action = "upload.php">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit"> 
     </form> 
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Check what your `$ext` contains?

Comment: When I try printing the value of these variables, it doesn't print anything, @MayankPandeyz

Comment: try add attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag

Comment: @ManyaAgarwal try `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag and see what happens ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz , Did. Resolves the error but the file isn't uploaded to the directory.

Comment: Check if the target path is valid and exist or not?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz The target path exists.

Comment: Issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag to send files with the form

Comment: The error is resolved, but the file is not being uploaded to the mentioned directory @Daniyal

Comment: changed the upload directory @ManyaAgarwal

Comment: makes no difference, the path exists.